# SPRESENSEでの定義済みマクロの定義方法

Tags: spresense

下記のように、コンパイラオプションによる事前定義マクロによって処理を分けたいです。

```
#ifdef HOGE
  処理1
#else
  処理2
#endif
```

SPRESENSE IDEの場合どのように行えば良いのでしょうか。
SDKコンフィグの設定を見回したりしましたが、見つかりませんでした。
どなたかご教授お願いいたします。

■環境
PC：Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
SDK：v2.0.1
IDE：v1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Sony Spresense SDKではオーソドックスなMakefileが使われているようです。

- [Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html)
- [Spresense SDK スタートガイド (CLI 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html)

Makefileの一般的な記法はWeb上に豊富な情報源が多数あるので、そちらをあたってください。
`HOGE`という名前を持つCのマクロ定数シンボルを定義したい場合、Makefile内で`CFLAGS`に`-D`オプションを追加することで、Cコンパイラに渡します。

```
CFLAGS += -DHOGE
```

Answer (score 0):

spressenceというより、C言語の問題ですね

ふつうは、それようのヘッダファイルを作って、そこにコンパイルスイッチ用マクロを記述する、という方法を使います。

また、コンパイルオプションでそれぞれのマクロの定義を行う、という方法もありますね